# Метод property() класса function в ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

В [документации](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Function.html#method_property) есть два примера использования function(){}.property():

Пример 1:

```
MyApp.President = Ember.Object.extend({
  firstName: '',
  lastName:  '',

  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');

    // Call this flag to mark the function as a property
  }.property()
});

var president = MyApp.President.create({
  firstName: "Barack",
  lastName: "Obama"
});

president.get('fullName');
```

и пример 2:

```
MyApp.President = Ember.Object.extend({
  firstName: '',
  lastName:  '',

  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');

    // Tell Ember.js that this computed property depends on firstName
    // and lastName
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});
```

**Вопрос:** какая между ними принципиальная разница? В [документации](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Function.html#method_property) так так туманно описана нужда второго способа, что я до конца не могу разобраться. Не хватает живого примера что-ли.

Активным большое спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Как я понял [отсюда](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ComputedProperty.html) это позволяет обновлять вычисляемые свойства только в случае если обновлено одно из свойств от которых зависит это вычисляемое свойство. Другими словами аргументами к методу property являются имена свойств от которых зависит вычисляемое свойство.

пример:

```
Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  // these will be supplied by `create`
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,
    otherprop: null,

  fullName: function() {
    console.log('fullName called');
    var firstName = this.get('firstName');
    var lastName = this.get('lastName');

   return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});

var tom = Person.create({
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Dale"
});

console.log(tom.get('fullName')); //вызовет fullName
console.log(tom.get('fullName')); //не вызовет
tom.set('otherprop',1);
console.log(tom.get('fullName')); //не вызовет
tom.set('firstName','Bill');
console.log(tom.get('fullName')); //вызовет

/*----------------*/

Person2 = Ember.Object.extend({
  // these will be supplied by `create`
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,
    otherprop: null,

  fullName: function() {
    console.log('fullName called');
    var firstName = this.get('firstName');
    var lastName = this.get('lastName');

   return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
  }.property()
});

var tom2 = Person2.create({
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Dale"
});

console.log(tom2.get('fullName')); //вызовет fullName
console.log(tom2.get('fullName')); //не вызовет 
tom2.set('otherprop',1);
console.log(tom2.get('fullName')); //не вызовет
tom2.set('firstName','Bill');
console.log(tom2.get('fullName')); //не изменит имя! и не вызовет
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/pDD3u/

ps: Ember вижу наверное второй раз в жизни, так что могу немного ошибаться

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/pDD3u/5/ так тоже работает :) это хорошо.

Comment: Пример не совсем верный, но идея правильная за старания плюсанул.

Comment: а чем не верный ?

Comment: @eicto совершенно верно объяснил, это используется для того чтобы указать от каких свойств зависит результат работы функции. Т.е. если зависимые свойства не изменились, то функция не будет заново проводить вычисления, а вернет закешированый результат.
P.S.: Есть опыт реализации достаточно большого проекта на EmberJS в связке с Symfony2 :). Но к сожалению большинство плюшек видны только после логина под админом.

Answer (score 0):

С релиза 1.12 рекомендуется использовать Ember.computed.
Примеры есть по [ссылке](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/05/13/ember-1-12-released.html). Плюс это предоставляет более удобный и корректный путь если необходимо написать не только геттер, но и сеттер.

И на мой вкус, при использовании кофе, синтаксис получается более наглядный.